# Permission denied using mkdir in PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu

I tried to create the directory `/home/freestyle/test` like this

```
$location = "/home/freestyle/test";
$uold     = umask(0);

mkdir($location,0777,true);
umask($uold);
```

but I get the error

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/test.php on line 6
```

I don't want to `chmod` permission via terminal, I want to do it in PHP directly.

How to do that?

Edit `ps aux | grep httpd` shown

```
root     10868  0.0  0.3 351528 14288 ?        Ss   09:41   0:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon   11263  0.0  0.1 347600  5500 ?        S    09:41   0:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon   11266  0.0  0.3 352036 11864 ?        S    09:41   0:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon   11267  0.0  0.3 352852 12864 ?        S    09:41   0:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon   11268  0.0  0.3 352036 11868 ?        S    09:41   0:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon   11269  0.0  0.3 352128 12308 ?        S    09:41   0:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon   11270  0.0  0.3 351944 11848 ?        S    09:41   0:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon   11329  0.0  0.3 352088 12088 ?        S    09:42   0:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon   11444  0.0  0.3 351900 11348 ?        S    09:44   0:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon   11922  0.0  0.2 351528 10572 ?        S    10:09   0:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon   11946  0.0  0.2 351528 10984 ?        S    10:10   0:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon   11953  0.0  0.2 351528 10120 ?        S    10:11   0:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
freestyle   12516  0.0  0.0  15124   984 pts/5    S+   10:42   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd
```

Comment: Does apache/httpd/w.e have ownership (or at least just read/write) in `/home/freestyle`?

Comment: The user PHP's running as would need permission to write to that directory.

Comment: `list -l` output on this folder and groups `yourusername` and pint it here

Comment: Which PHP version is this? php --version

Comment: @AzizSaleh i use `PHP 5.5.9`

Answer (score 4):

You first need to make sure you have the right permissions for `/home/freestyle/`
to do this run `ls -l /home/freestyle/` from your terminal

than run (*depending on your apache configs, in my case it's www-data)

```
chown "www-data:www-data" /home/freestyle/
```

and `ls -l /home/freestyle/` again to see if permission changed

UPDATE*

from the output you've provided it looks like your apache runs under `daemon`.
to give permissions for /home/freestyle/ run:

```
chown "daemon:daemon" /home/freestyle/
```

UPDATE 2*

to change apache ownership user and group, change/add the following in your apache configs

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

Comment: i use ls -ld `/home/freestyle/` and results is `drwxr-xr-x 28`

Comment: what's in the owner column?

Comment: it's `drwxr-xr-x 28 freestyle freestyle 4096 Th03  9 08:28 /home/freestyle/`

Comment: what's the output of `ps aux | grep apache | head -n1`

Comment: is `freestyle   12359  0.0  0.0  15120   980 pts/5    S+   10:32   0:00 grep --color=auto apache`

Comment: probably apache not running under "apache" or you didn't run it with sudo try again `sudo ps aux | grep apache` if nothing shows up try `sudo ps aux | grep httpd`

Comment: try `chown "daemon:daemon" /home/freestyle/`

Comment: why `chmod /home/freestyle/`, can i chmod `chown "freestyle:freestyle" /opt/lampp/bin/httpd` or anything like via php script?

Comment: no. because apache doesn't run under `freestyle` he runs under `demon` , to performe mkdir php has to have permissions in the first place.

Comment: i want do all in php file b/c i want all is auto when i setup?